# Prove $\|x\|_1\le \sqrt n \|x\|_2$

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces

Prove

$$\|x\|_2 \le  \|x\|_1 \le \sqrt n\|x\|_2. \forall x \in \mathbb{R}^n$$

I already proved the first inequality $\|x\|_2 \le \|x\|_1$. Please help me with the second part:

$$\|x\|_1\le \sqrt n \|x\|_2.$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint:

$$\| x\|_1 = |x_1| + \cdots + |x_n| = (1, 1, \cdots, 1)\cdot (|x_1|, |x_2|, \cdots, |x_n|).$$

Comment: Please give more detail.

Comment: What did you try? @Kevin

Comment: I do not know where I can start.

Comment: I use this |<x,y>| ≤√<x,x>·<y,y>

Comment: Thank you so much for your hint @John Ma